# How do I convert a date/time stamp into a date variable so I can find how long a meeting takes?

Tags: r, date

I am working on a project where I have to find out how long meetings are taking. I have two columns "STARTDATE" and "END DATE" and they are character variables. I want to subtract end date from start date to get how long the meeting takes

I have tried using `as.POSIXct` to convert the variable, but it keeps throwing an error.

```
STARTDATE                           ENDDATE
9  18-JAN-19 10.42.30.000000000 AM  18-JAN-19 11.01.24.000000000 AM
10 18-JAN-19 10.43.02.000000000 AM  18-JAN-19 11.02.42.000000000 AM
11 18-JAN-19 10.44.04.000000000 AM  18-JAN-19 11.05.57.000000000 AM
13 18-JAN-19 10.41.34.000000000 AM  18-JAN-19 10.53.21.000000000 AM
```

and I tried

```
as.POSIXct(df$STARTDATE, format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

All I get is

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: Your format string doesn't match the data you showed. Hours, minutes, and seconds are separated by `.`, not `:` as in your `as.POSIXct`. There also appears to be miliseconds and AM/PM indicator, which isn't listed in you call to `as.POSIXct`

Comment: @divibisan any idea why this doesn't work? ```as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%OS %p")```

Comment: That works fine for me. What is `x`? If `x` is the whole data.frame, that's the problem: `as.POSIXct` expects a vector, so you need to do something like `x$STARTDATE <- as.POSIXct(x$STARTDATE ...`

Comment: @divibisan ```x <- "18-JAN-19 10.42.30.000000000 PM"``` it almost works, but not considering *AM/PM*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `format` argument doesn't match the actual date format:

1. Hours, minutes and seconds are separated by `.` instead of `:`
2. Your data has both  milliseconds and an AM/PM separator

Data (I've modified the last value of `ENDDATE` to include a PM time because it reveals an important edge case):

```
df <- structure(list(STARTDATE = c("18-JAN-19 10.42.30.000000000 AM", 
    "18-JAN-19 10.43.02.000000000 AM", "18-JAN-19 10.44.04.000000000 AM", 
    "18-JAN-19 10.41.34.000000000 AM"), ENDDATE = c("18-JAN-19 11.01.24.000000000 AM", 
    "18-JAN-19 11.02.42.000000000 AM", "18-JAN-19 11.05.57.000000000 AM", 
    "18-JAN-19 10.53.21.000000000 PM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L))
```

If you fix your `format` argument and then apply it to each date vector, you'll find it converts them to POSIXct format:

```
df$STARTDATE <- as.POSIXct(df$STARTDATE, format = "%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%OS %p")
df$ENDDATE <- as.POSIXct(df$ENDDATE, format = "%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%OS %p")

            STARTDATE             ENDDATE
1 2019-01-18 10:42:30 2019-01-18 11:01:24
2 2019-01-18 10:43:02 2019-01-18 11:02:42
3 2019-01-18 10:44:04 2019-01-18 11:05:57
4 2019-01-18 10:41:34 2019-01-18 22:53:21

class(df$STARTDATE)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

You'll note that the format lists `%I.%M.%OS` instead of `%H.%M.%OS` because `%I` (Hours from 01-12) must be used with AM/PM times, not `%H` (Hours from 0-23). Thanks [M-M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6461462/m-m) for catching this!

See `?strptime`:

> %p ... Used in conjunction with %I and not with %H

Comment: Well you have that problem too! Check it with a PM time!

Comment: @M-M Good catch! You need to use `%I` instead of `%H` if using AM/PM. I've fixed that now

Comment: Awwwww. It's been bugging me for an hour why that first version would not work. Something obvious but I just was not seeing it. Cheers.